# Listing folders and sub-folders in DOS and Unix?

Tags: dos

I have to list folders and sub-folders from a given directory in DOS and Unix. I know i cand make this with DIR command, as follows: `dir directory /ad /s`, but the assignment tells me that I have to make it with find. It works with dir, but i have no idea how to make it with find. And I have to make it in UNIX too, so if you have some hints or something, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows native `find` command is for finding strings in files or stdin, not for listing file names. download [findutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) for windows, then you can use `find` the same as what you used in Unix

WindowS:

```
C:\test> gnu_find.exe c:\path
```

Unix:

```
find /path
```